# Excluding all files of a type in NuGet

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, nuget-package

**Problem**: I have .sql files in my Visual Studio project which I want to exclude from my NuGet package. These .sql files are nested into various directories, and I have been unable to successfully exclude all .sql files from my nuget package.

---

**1:** I've created a .nuspec file by running the following command on my target project:

```
nuget spec
```

**2:** I've edited the resulting nuspec file so that it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Security Core Impl</description>
    <releaseNotes>Security Core Impl</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2013</copyright>
    <tags>Security Core</tags>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="**\*.dll" target="lib\net40\" exclude="**\*.sql;" />
  </files>
</package>
```

**3:** I run the following command to build my .nupkg:

```
nuget pack -Prop Configuration=Release
```

---

Whenever I install this package into another project, however, the .sql files get included.  I've tried a few different variations of the exclude above, and have tried the -Exclude switch. Nothing seems to work.

All .sql files are marked:

- Build Action: None
- Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy

I have also tried clearing my NuGet cache via Visual Studio options.

**Note:** The NuGet package is hosted on a private server.

Comment: Did you try to do this without nuspec? I mean remove generated nuspec and execute `nuget pack myproj.csproj -Exclude **\*.sql -Prop Configuration=Release`

Comment: Did you intend to put a semicolon after .sql? This works for me `<file src="bin\dynamic-debug\*.dll" target="(path)" exclude="**\*unwanted.dll" />`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've just been having the exact same issue, but with .txt files. The solution as pointed out by a colleague is to change the **Build Action** from "Content" to "None".

Comment: (facepalm) I'm still curious why OP (and I) can't get exclude to work, but thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your *.sql files are under the `content` folder of the package?

`<file src="**\*.dll" target="lib\net40\" exclude="**\*.sql;" />` tells NuGet to add all .DLL files under lib\net40.  SQL files are ignored as your include didn't include them anyway.

Can you try adding `<file target="content\" exclude="**\*.sql;" />` to the nuspec?

Comment: adding <file target="content\" exclude="**\*.sql;" /> causes an error: NotSpecified: (The required attribute 'src' is missing.:String)